# Java , how to call a method from the main method

Tags: java

There is something wrong with my method sum100 that for some odd reason doesn't return the value of all integers between 1 and 100, all help is appreciated.

```
public class Blandat {

public int sum100 (){

    for (int i =1 ; i<=100; i++){
        int summa=0;
        summa = summa+i;

    }

    return summa;
}
```

}

Main Method

```
public class MainBlandat {
public static void main (String[] args){

    Blandat b = new Blandat();
    System.out.println(b.sum100);


}
```

}

Comment: What is the scope of the variable `summa`?

Comment: You're setting its value to 0 for every iteration.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Beat me in 3 seconds. :)

Comment: b.sum100 -> b.sum100() and don't set summa = 0 in the iteration

Comment: Call me my method sum100 ().

Comment: this code won't even compile. you should get a compile error when compiling above. The compile error gives you a strong hint about what is going wrong. This looks like homework to me

Answer (score 5):

You're initializing it in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    int summa = 0;
    summa = summa + i;
}
```

Try initializing it outside:

```
int summa = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    summa = summa + i;
}
```

Comment: I prefer `summa += i;`

Comment: use foreach we are living in 2013.

Comment: @nikpon The idea of using foreach is sort of silly here, since there's no collection or array to iterate over.

Comment: @nikpon I'm confused. How would you choose to write this loop construct?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Are you asking me or someone else who'd like to explain you the silly idea out there.

Comment: @nikpon You said `use foreach we are living in 2013` I'm still trying to understand that comment. Can you post your `2013` way of solving this? I'm a bit confused and eager to learn the `2013` way of doing this

Comment: @nikpon Since I addressed my comment to you, I thought I was asking you. It's a real question. The regular `for` loop seems a fine choice to me here. I haven't done serious java since the pre-foreach 1.4 days, though, so I'd be happy to hear a better way to do handle this specific case.

Comment: @nikpon Sheesh dude, why be evasive? Just show a little code! This "oh you probably wouldn't understand anyway" routine is just weird.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring summa inside your for loop but you return it outside the loop. Was it also declared on another level?